# Not Registering Chef Node while knife bootstrap

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping

I am using Chef-11.16.2. While bootstrapping the windows/Linux Nodes , it throws the error , client.pem is not present.

I had fetch the ssl certificate using knife ssl fetch.

**Problem is that**  when I try to "knife ssl check" it downloads the "localhost.localdomain" certificate from the chef server due to which knife ssl check , keep looking for localhost.localdomain instead of Chef-server url.

In my organization chef is already setup so , I can't generate the ssl certificate again.

## Below is my knife.rb configuration

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'admin'
#client_key               '~/.chef/test.pem'
client_key               '~/.chef/admin.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '~/.chef/validation.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://test.com:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '~/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path            '~/chef/cookbooks'
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

Is there any way to resolve the issue ? Please help me out.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an SSL issue (additionally you've configured your workstation to ignore SSL verification). I think you need to show your failing knife bootstrap command. To be honest the error sounds more like a problem running chef client. To be certain, which don't you remove the "/etc/chef" directory on the server you're trying to bootstrap and see if that helps.

Comment: <pre>Yes , absolutely right , I am trying to bootstrap the windows 2008R2 server and linux as well. Couple of times I had uninstall the chef server and delete the /etc/chef folder. Yes, I am trying to ignore SSL verification. But somehow , chef client looking for the SSL. Everytime I run the knife bootstrap , like knife bootstrap windows winrm <IP Address> -x '<username>' -p 5985 --bootstrap-version 11.16.2 -P <password> -N abc.example.com. </pre><br>It throws client.pem is not present , "To verify , run the following command knife ssl check"</br>

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, When I try to run the knife ssl check. It start looking for localhost.localdomain because chef-server certificate is created as localhost.localdomain , not created as per domain name

Comment: Is this a 401 error message? See: https://docs.chef.io/errors.html#failed-to-authenticate-as-organization-validator

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, Issue has been resolved. Actually , it was due to some --bootstrap-proxy in knife command. When I removed that line , it worked on the node. Thanks for your great help !!!